# Weird dash character in PHP

Tags: php

I have a weird dash in my text, which isn't being detected in a `str_replace`.

Here is an example:

`Sun: 10:00 – 3:00pm`

I don't know if the dash will show up on here.. but when it is inserted into my table, it is like a square box with the characters `0096`

It looks a lot like an `&ndash;` - when viewing the source, there is no special characters, just the dash.

```
str_replace('–', '', $var);
```

The above replace doesn't seem to catch it, has anyone else had this trouble before?

Comment: you should give us the string in [base64_encode](http://www.php.net/base64_encode) format, so that its preserved binary safe. This makes it ez for us to identify the character.

Comment: Just asking the obvious but are you saving the return value of str_replace? I.e. `$var = str_replace('–', '', $var);` str_replace doesn't do operations directly on the string.

Comment: What character set is your table using?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

That's an [**en dash**](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/2013/index.htm). In php, the most portable way to get it is with [`html_entity_decode`](http://php.net/html_entity_decode):

```
$endash = html_entity_decode('&#x2013;', ENT_COMPAT, 'UTF-8');
echo str_replace($endash, '(en dash)', 'Sun: 10:00 – 3:00pm');
```

Note that this only works if your website encoding is UTF-8 **and** your editor encoding(or the encoding of the third argument to `str_replace`) is as well. If you use another encoding (and you should use the same both for website and editor), replace the third parameter of html_entity_decode with its name.

Answer (score 1):

For an alternative, if other answers don't work for you, like in my case, this works for me.

```
$title = "Hunting, Tactical & Outdoor Optics eCommerce Store ΓÇô $595,000 ΓÇö SOLD";
$title = str_replace(html_entity_decode('&ndash;', ENT_COMPAT, 'UTF-8'), '-', $title);
$title = str_replace(html_entity_decode('&mdash;', ENT_COMPAT, 'UTF-8'), '-', $title);
```

Answer (score 0):

En `-` Dash we're used to seeing
Em `–` Dash that we're supposed to use most of the time where use "-".
Basically, it's a grammar thing.

Read up on Wikipedia: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dash

*On a mac (with US Keyboard Layout) I get it hitting Alt+- , same as you get _ with shift+_*

You don't need any special treatement to it as it were some chinese symbol. It is a valid character. Treat it as such: `str_replace('–', 'em dash');`.

Answer (score 0):

http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php#102465
jay suggested

```
$str = str_replace(chr(150), '-–', $str);    // endash
$str = str_replace(chr(151), '--', $str);   // emdash
```