# Split a string with <span> using preg_split()

Tags: php, regex, string, split

I have a sting that is in this format.

```
<span class="amount">$25</span>–<span class="amount">$100</span>
```

What I need to do is split that into two strings. The string will remain in the same format but the prices will change. I tried using str_split() but because the price changes I wouldn't be able to always know how many characters to split the string at.

What I am trying to get is something like this.

String 1

```
<span class="amount">$25</span>–
```

String 2

```
<span class="amount">$100</span>
```

It seems the best option I have found is to use preg_split() but I don't know anything about regex so I'm not sure how to format the expression. There may also be a better way to handle this and I just don't know of it.

Could someone please help me format the regex, or let me know of a better way to split that string.

#### Edit

Thanks to @rm-vanda for helping me figure out that I don't need to use preg_split for this. I was able to split the string using explode(). The issue I was having was because the '-' was encoded weird and therefore not returning correctly.

Comment: Try parsing it properly instead of using a regex ([see this for more info](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags))

Comment: *"It seems the best option I have found is to use preg_split()"* - you need to do more research. See [Parsing Html The Cthulhu Way](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2009/11/parsing-html-the-cthulhu-way.html)

Comment: Thank you for the reference material, I think it is clear that using regex on html is not a good idea. However, I don't know what my other options are at this point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it always has the "-" then this would be the most simple way:

```
$span = explode("-", $spans); 

echo $span[0]; 

echo $span[1];
```

Comment: There is always going to be a "-" so this option seems like it would work. However I can't seem to get it correct. It always returns one array item with the entire string in it.

Comment: When I copy+pasted your code, the "-" seems to be some other character -- (for example, ctrl+f and search for "-" - and the "-" in your code does not get hit)
Just replace it in your code with "-"

Comment: I tried this two different ways but couldn't get it to work. http://pastebin.com/10DB6iCN

Comment: Ok I will try and see what the character is that's being used, it's being created inside of a plugin that I can't edit, so hopefully I can figure it out.

Comment: The character is called the EN_DASH  and this will solve your problem, albeit, you may be able to cut a line out if you try. http://phpfiddle.org/lite/code/u97-1c3

Comment: taken from: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9027472/weird-dash-character-in-php

Answer (score 3):

It might be better to translate this problem into DOM:

```
$html = <<<HTML
<span class="amount">$25</span>–<span class="amount">$100</span>
HTML;

$doc = new DOMDocument;
$doc->loadHTML($html);

foreach ($doc->getElementsByTagName('span') as $span) {
    // do stuff with $span
    // e.g. this is how you would get the outer html
    echo $doc->saveXML($span);
}
```

Comment: No . 

No it is not. 

DOM takes way more memory - and this is far too simple of an operation to justify such large overhead.

Comment: @rm-vanda What OP wants to do with it later would make the difference; that said, in most cases I've seen the string domain is the wrong one for HTML.

Comment: You agree, then - that if he only has two spans that DOM is not the right way to go?

Comment: @rm-vanda Sure, *if* that's the case ... at this point we both don't know, do we?

Comment: No, but it is certainly good to enumerate all the possibilities.

Comment: @rm-vanda Indeed, but I don't see how that's worth a downvote.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/48208/discussion-between-rm-vanda-and-jack)

Comment: I am only going to have those two spans, if that helps at all.