# How to replace or strip out ndash character from a string?

Tags: php

The problem looks simple, but it's taking time to figure out.
I need to get rid of ndash characters from some strings in a project. Not the HTML entity **&ndash;**, but the actual character ( **–** ). Using str_replace() and preg_replace() didn't work.

Already tried:

```
$new_str = str_replace('–', '', $str_with_ndash_char);
```

Also tried:

```
$new_str = preg_replace('/–/', '', $str_with_ndash_char);
```

Also, it's a legacy project. Some parts of it are iso-8859-1 encoded, and a few others are utf-8 encoded. I noticed that my editor (Komodo Edit) complains about the ndash character when a PHP file is iso-8859-1, losing the character when I save the file, like this:

```
$new_str = str_replace('?', '', $str_with_ndash_char);
```

Converting everything to utf-8 results in a lot of garbage characters (same for the other way around, converting everything to iso-8859-1), so I'm avoiding doing it unless it's really, really necessary.

**Edited:** removed double $ signs (bad CTRL+V).

Answer (score 1):

I just tried out what you are doing and worked just fine, make sure that is is n-dashed in the string and not em-dashes.

I tried replacing both the different types and found no issues.

```
$str = str_replace('—', '', '–test—');   
echo $str . '</br>';
$str = str_replace('–', '', $str);     
echo $str;
```

This gives me the result:

```
-test
test
```

Some more concrete example would be nice as well. Like the strings you are trying to change and not just the variables.

Comment: For example, this string: 

"Tributário – Trabalhista – Previdenciário – Tempo de Guarda de Documentos"

Comment: Running 
`$str = str_replace('–', '', "Tributário – Trabalhista – Previdenciário – Tempo de Guarda de Documentos");`
works just fine for me

Comment: What if you tried both my methods I posted on the same string and echoed them out between takes? Any difference?

Comment: No difference. 
The string comes form an iso-8859-1 encoded page. Could it be changed somehow when I try to replace it in an utf-8 encoded module?

Comment: You tried to convert the string to UTF-8 you said, what method are you using?

Comment: At first I was passing the string to the utf8_encode function, then I also did try mb_convert_encoding. Both had no effect.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that error is in redundant $ sign.
It should be exactly one dollar sign in a variable.
So the line `$new_str = str_replace('–', '', $str_with_ndash_char);` should work fine.

But if it all OK in code in your project, the you should [check out this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9027536/7825433)

Also, try to switch error reportin mode to E_ALL. Place
`error_reporting(E_ALL);` on the top of your script

Comment: Double $ sign was my bad while posting the question.

Answer (score 0):

Finally solved it:

```
$new_str = preg_replace("/[^[:alnum:]]/", '', $old_str)
```

**Be warned** that this will remove everything that's not alphanumeric, not just the ndash character. In my case, I don't need any character other than the alphanumeric ones.